# PHP from root user, mkdir permission denied

Tags: php, linux, command-line, permissions, zend-framework2

Today I have encountered a strange behaviour which I do not understand.
I am trying to create a directory on the local disk using a **PHP 7.0** script using `mkdir()` function but it produces a *"permission denied"* error.

In my experience (although very little) this always meant that the user which is executing the PHP script is not authorized to write to the directory. This makes sense to me and is usually not a problem *when developing web applications*. The default PHP user when using Apache is `www-data` and I don't encounter problems with it.

In this case though I am using **Zend Framework 2** and in particular I am using it's console routes so I am not going through Apache (correct me if I am wrong). I am calling my script as:

```
php index.php route name [--options]
```

with my user (which is **not root** but is a **sudoer**). The problems start if I output the result of PHP's `get_current_user()` function because I get *'root'* instead of my expected user name. Not only this, but I get *'permission denied'* when using `mkdir()` in the following directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 19 21:21 logs
```

What I understand from this is that I probably am not the root user as PHP seems to suggest. If I then run the script with *'sudo'* in front I am able to create the desired folders but the permissions do not match the ones I specify in my `mkdir()` function. If I write `mkdir('path', 0777)` I then get:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root
```

This I do not understand. So, if someone could help me figure out what I am doing wrong I would be very thankful. Keep in mind that the fact that I am going through Zend Framework 2 might influence this behaviour (although I am not keen on thinking so).

Thank you in advance for your time.

Edit.

I just realized I didn't tell you what my final goal is so I will now put things in context, sorry.

What I am trying to do is to use this script (run either from **root** or from **my user**, preferably from **my user**) to create these folders inside

```
/var/www
```

and to then be able to read and write files (and possibly other folders) to those directories whith the standard **PHP** user which in my case is **www-data**

Comment: Maybe selinux is causing issues?

Comment: Not sure why get_current_user() is returning "root" however it is correct that your user shouldn't be able to write to that logs directory. I assume you aren't in the www-data group and it is not world writable. As a side note, please don't create 777 directories. I understand it was for testing but use UNIX groups or setfacl.

Comment: Ahah, the good old "don't use 777" reccomendation. I understand, thank you. I'm just using it as a way to help me pinpoint the problem more easily without having to worry about permissions (on a vm, with nothing important on it, in my pc, so don't worry). I edited the question so maybe you can help me out further now

Answer (score -1):

your php runned as apache extension, and using apache permissions. 
If you need to create folder as root, you can create cron script for it, which will monitor change in some file, and create directory as root.
Another way to do it, using suid extension, but it a bit complicated.

Comment: He states in the question that he's running a script from the command line as root.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have edited my question with some additional information on what my actual goal is so that you may be able to help me out a bit more. I am not able to solve my problem with your current answer